# 1993 Honda Civic keeps blowing the 50 amp fuse under the hood

Tags: honda, civic, fuse

I replaced the ignition switch first, since in my Haynes book, it is what is directly connected to the fuse.  The car works fine for a day then blows the fuse again.

Comment: i put new fuse in, drive 25 miles on highway. let it sit all day while at work, then at 5pm try to start and the fuse is blown. put new fuse in and repeat. tried putting in a new ignition switch  and lock. same thing still. any ideas?

Comment: can you expand on what the fuse powers? does the ignition switch pass power to the fuse or is it the other way around?

Comment: Do not do not do change the fuse to a larger one. Fuses are sized to protect the wiring in your car. If your fuse is burning out something is causing that. You will have to isolate things and figure it out. Easiest way is remove battery from circuit measure resistance with multimeter.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the wiring diagram for that fuse and your manual see it probably hooks to a lot of things. Find out what else the fuse is connected to. 50 amps is a pretty big fuse so that might just be the main fuse for the entire car. If that's the case you need to look at your wiring diagram and see what electrical circuits get energized when the ignition switch is just initially turned on. Blowing such a large fuse means you probably have a short to ground and you'll need to trace the wires (both in the diagram and physically) and you'll probably find a charred wire some place. Unless it's something obvious that you can see quickly you may just be better off taking it to an automotive electrician to find the short.

Answer (score 0):

Your starter is starting to go bad and is drawing too much current.  Pull the starter out and take it your your FLAPS to get tested.  Then replace the starter.